# automatically compare prices with ready-made codes

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I want to prepare a site to automatically compare prices with ready-made codes. I found a dashboard with ready-made codes on Bootstrap. Hosting was purchased for me to start the process. Now how can I continue the process? Are there sites for videos or other information?

Code to try: I have 1 year of knowledge.

Comment: This is not the platform to ask "questions" like this. Please seek help on a much more suitable platform. Which is not this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.